# Cannot get code to email file as an attachment once the submit button is clicked on

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have created a form for users to fill out and submit. The idea is that once submit is clicked on it immediately emails the completed excel form as an attachment to a specific email address.

But what actually happens is that it sends the email without the attachment. Can you help please, the VBA currently in place is

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
  Dim objOutlook As Object
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
  Dim objEmail As Object
  Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With objEmail
    .To = "temi.akinnaike@asos.com"
    .Subject = "Issue Resolution Request"
    .Body = "Hi Finance Systems, please see the attached issues log for your attention"
    .Send        ' SEND THE MESSAGE.
    .Save
    'Add the active workbook as an attachment
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\SLA & addnl details form 3 - without VBA for flie attachment.xlsm"
  End With

  ' CLEAR.
  Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:
'
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not because you add the attachment after the send and save?

Comment: @Temi, did the code below solve your problem? If so, I'd appreciate you marking it as the correct answer :)  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks so much for your response. I had already made the correction and made it work and yes you are right about the problem being that the code runs a rountine to send the email before adding the attachment. I revised my code and it works but - its now sending the completed form as a blank one. Can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code as follows:

```
With objEmail
    .To = "temi.akinnaike@asos.com"
    .Subject = "Issue Resolution Request"
    .Body = "Hi Finance Systems, please see the attached issues log for your attention"
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\SLA & addnl details form 3 - without VBA for flie attachment.xlsm"
    .Send        ' SEND THE MESSAGE.
    .Save
End With
```

The issue is that you are adding the attachment after you are sending the mail.

Also note that this issue may be caused by a typographical mistake in the parameters for the  .Attachments.Add option?

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\SLA & addnl details form 3 - without VBA for flie attachment.xlsm"
```

Maybe it should be

```
"...file attachment.xlsm"
```